# Filtering using a class or data attribute using List.js

Tags: javascript, listjs

If I have an HTML list like this:

```
<div id="my-list">
    <ul class="list">
        <li data-cat="fish">Cod</li>
        <li data-cat="fish">Salmon</li>
        <li data-cat="bird">Crow</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is it possible to filter it based on the contents of the `data-cat` attribute using [List.js](http://www.listjs.com)?

All the examples I've seen only allow searching/filtering based on visible HTML content, but I'd like to filter based on the content of a `data` element, as here, or maybe the list item's `class`. I can't see how to do this though.

Comment: Take a look at the reference. It is not a feature at the moment. You could however take a look at the custom filter function in the options object. Depending on what type the ``item`` is, you get there as an argument, you could write your own filtering function which works like you want.

Comment: Thanks. After writing this I thought maybe I was over-thinking it and should just use jQuery to find and hide/show elements with matching classes/data elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery instead of [list.js](http://www.listjs.com/) to find and hide/show elements with matching classes/data elements [as you commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766658/filtering-using-a-class-or-data-attribute-using-list-js#comment57280637_34766658), you can simply use `.filter`.

For example, if you want to hide the items with `fish` as `data-cat`:

```js
$('.list li').filter('[data-cat="fish"]').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-list">
    <ul class="list">
        <li data-cat="fish">Cod</li>
        <li data-cat="fish">Salmon</li>
        <li data-cat="bird">Crow</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```